# How To Password Protect a Static Site in Azure

Tags: azure, security

I have a static site (i.e all html files, no .Net project) that is being hosted in Azure. I'm trying to password protect this site. I've read that I could create a custom authorisation module, which I've done, but I can't install this as I need to run a appcmd.exe command to allow the correct bit of the web.config to be edited.

Either; how can I password protect a static azure site, or how can I take advantage of the features of the ServiceDefinition.csdef without having a visual studio project?

Comment: Even though it's a static site, can't you still publish it from Visual Studio with a custom web.config file with the module setup?  Are you using a standard web role to install your Azure app?

Comment: The site content is auto generated from a ruby frank project (haml and static content), it's not very compatible with a VS project. Yes it's a standard web role (I think, I'm very new to Azure).

Comment: OK. If you are packaging up the files and sending to web role, I believe you can include a web.config at the root with custom settings.  Try adding one to your build artifacts with the module registered, and a .dll containing your custom module as part of the project.

Comment: Your question caught my attention because we've done this exact same thing with custom authentication / authorization module with a web role.  However, our project is implemented in .Net with Visual Studio, so I don't know how it really works outside of the IDE environment.

Comment: Ok, naive question, 'packaging up the files'? I'm just pushing them to github and then I have a custom script (via .deployment) that xcopies the files to the target directory.

Comment: I see. You are using the new github continuous deployment to Azure?  I've read about it, but don't know too much.  However I'd be curious to know what happens if you simply add a file called "web.config" to the root of your github project and see if it is incorporated?

Comment: The web.config is incorporated correctly, but for the custom module I have to set `<windowsAuthentication enabled="false"/>` and `<anonymousAuthentication enabled="false"/>` which isn't permitted, unless I run an elevated appcmd to enable setting these, which I can't seem to figure out.

Comment: OK. Can you show what you've tried for your `<Startup>` task?  Also, have you tried the Azure emulator?  It can be very helpful for debugging, because it's a quicker lifecycle and you get more information about what is going on. Also, do you have RDP enabled to your roles so you can connect and see what's going on in a pinch?

Comment: Sure, https://gist.github.com/ilivewithian/5406774 and https://gist.github.com/ilivewithian/5406784 but since I don't have a VS project, I can't see how to get Azure to run these.

Comment: You mention "all html files, no .Net project"...But you have a web.config?

Answer (score 5):

On the management portal, you can configure that your site needs to use credentials. Credentials are managed via the Azure portal if you use this method. [image]

Comment: Is their a documentation for that?

Answer (score 0):

You could use [Forms Authentication](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-gb/library/7t6b43z4%28v=vs.100%29.aspx) which should be pretty straightforward to implement and won't require any startup task (necessary to run appcmd.exe).

Set your application to use forms authentication in your web.config.

```
<authentication mode="Forms">
  <forms name=".ASPXAUTH" loginUrl="/myadminlogin.aspx" protection="All" path="/" timeout="120" />
</authentication>
```

Define the protected folders in your web.config.

```
 <location path="secure">
    <system.web>
      <authorization>
        <deny users="?" />
      </authorization>
    </system.web>
  </location>
```

Within your login area check a condition and set the auth cookie:

```
    'SET AUTH COOKIE
    FormsAuthentication.SetAuthCookie(sessionID, False)
    response.redirect(/secure/securearea.html)
```

This unfortunately is the one page where you will need some server side code.